# Scaled ColorData Function

Tags: plotting, color

I have a four-dimensional array `c`, in which the first dimension represents time and the other three dimensions represent `(x,y,z)` (space).
The values represent the density of a gas at the coordinates.
I want to plot the 3D values with `Manipulate[]`:

```
Manipulate[ListContourPlot3D[c[[a, All, All, All]],PlotRange->{-4, 4},ImageSize->800,
Mesh->None,ColorFunction->(ColorData["TemperatureMap"][#4]&),Contours->7,
ContourStyle->Opacity[0.4]],{a,1,150,1}]
```

The problem is that at `c[[1,All,All,All]]` the values range between 0 and 16, while the values at `c[[150,All,All,All]]` all hover around 4. (This is a simulation of a gas diffusion.)

I'd like the scale to remain steady, so that eventually around `a = 150`, the entire plot is more or less light blue over the entire domain.

Comment: Yes, I just read that one in the related section, can't believe I didn't find that one while searching.